# Removing Empty Object from Doc Function

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to remove properties with falsy values from an object before saving that object, but for some reason my function is not removing a property where the value is an empty object.

Here is the object to be cleaned (note: `transaction` is an empty object):

```
let obj = { _id: 1,
  transaction: {},
  deleted: false,
  name: { long: 'Test' },
  createdAt: '2019-07-15T14:37:24.390Z',
  updatedAt: '2019-07-15T14:37:24.390Z',
  __v: 0 
}
```

Here is the function:

```
function cleanObj(obj) {
  for (let propName in obj) {
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined) {
        delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
}
```

When I console log out the object after the function's run, `transaction` is still part of the object. What am I missing here?

Comment: Use == (equality) instead of === (identity comparison). `false === undefined` and `false === null` both return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transaction` has a value of `{}` which is not a falsey value.

You should check to see if the object is empty:

```js
const obj = {}
const isObjectEmpty = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).length === 0

console.log(isObjectEmpty(obj))
```

Comment: Thanks. In other words, this would handle it:
`      async function cleanObj(obj) {
        for (let propName in obj) {
          if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined || Object.keys(obj[propName]).length === 0) {
            delete obj[propName];
          }
        }
        return obj;
      }`

Comment: Yep. That should work fine. It'd be better off as it's own function though, so you could re-use it in the future.

Comment: Also, it's better to use `typeof obj[propName] === 'undefined'`.

Comment: And I also don't think there's a need for that to be an async function.

Comment: Good point on 'typeof'. In regards to making each check into its own function, I think that purely depends on one's use case. It's not always better to do that.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But if you want to make your code self-documenting, then it's the better alternative. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/5o4g2znw/ . To a new person joining the project, they won't need to know the implementation details of all those helper functions if they need to add another check to `cleanObj `. This is an arbitrary example but the point is to reduce maintenance overhead.

Comment: I see your point, and I agree. It's a little more verbose, but clearer and more maintainable because it's more modular.